# How to make a responsive two color background?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So this is what I'm trying to accomplish:

Desktop image:

[image: Desktop image]

Mobile image:

[image: Mobile image]

I already have the boxes but I don't know how to add a 2 color background. I'm using bootstrap.

This is my code so far

```css
body {
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
}

#container {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      BOX 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:20px">
      BOX 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div clas="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:20px">
      BOX 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post the html/css you have so far.

Comment: Please add code which you tried to achieve it.

Comment: Look into CSS gradients. In the future, please ask a more specific question and provide a sample of your code attempt.

Comment: Already added the code, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this via `linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007cc1 100px, #fff 100px);
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```